# How to model this cylinder type shape with pattern

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: I want to create this shape]

[image: And I am only able to come up with this]

I want to create above shape (first image)
and I only could come up with this (second image)

Maybe some new tips and tricks which would help me in my way?

Answer (score 0):

You can subdivide your result vertically and horizontally and then select four vertices and extrude them out. The basic extrusion principle would help you in your way.